# Google Sheets: Sum a Value Range Within a Specified Time Frame

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs

I'm trying to sum a range of values, within a given time frame. The time frame could be x hours, or y days, etc. An example:
[image]

So for **each** row, I need to sum the last hours or days as specified in cells C2:E2, which are *numeric* (just added formatting to show the text).  Note that the datetime values do not follow any interval pattern, but are always sequential.

Although I've tried searching SO, and via Google, I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

[Edit]
I've added to a link to an example sheet of what I'm trying to do... pls just ask if I can add any further info!
[Test Sum By Time](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aHQUw5A9km7GwgfbvpuHA-YvJx1hy9FpKCS0XfpahB8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: OK, will will do, and advise when done. Have to move it to a separate workbook.

Comment: Spreadsheet added, pls let me know if I need to explain further.  I've manually added some values together, you can see that the number of cells varies, so that it's always within the timeframe specified in C2:C3.  It would be helpful if a function allowed me to change the number of hours, and/or the number of days, and the Sum changed accordingly.

Comment: About sharing spreadsheets, do note that [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private.

Comment: Accessing a public legal api as mentioned in the meta question can by no means considered hacking.

Comment: That's not the issue. Usually the point is linking your accounts. We know this stackoverflow, reddit, bank   accounts are associated with the same email.  Check at https://haveibeenpwned.com It can be used to profile you and track you or even scam you. "I got nothing to hide" or "It's just a email" is a bad way to approach privacy. And no,  You can't get someone's email address, if they didn't share the sheet. Furthermore, all I'm doing is responsibly informing. It's up to the user to do what they want with that info.

Comment: Google forum members went to the trouble of creating [Blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to avoid this. Not everyone is just happy with throwing their email around to random people. Furthermore, questions here need to add value to the community, not just the user. Adding a sheet is a sure way to know that the question is bad and not minimal or descriptive enough.

Comment: Sorry, just got back after minding my grandkids.  @Erik Tyler:  As per your first comment I have added a few random  "example" results to the shared spreadsheet.  The intent was to show that the range which was summed will vary in size, in order to encompass the desired timeframe.  In my OP I did mention that an equation is needed for each row.  Sorry, I thought this was almost self-explanatory.

Comment: @TheMaster: I had no idea that sharing a Google Spreadsheet would expose my email address!  It's the first time I've done this. I'll check out the link to the blank sheet maker - thank you - I was unaware this existed. My bad. :(

Comment: @Erik:  I used the method suggested in the Answer by 'player0' and modified it a bit - now works exactly as I had intended. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Erik Tyler:  True, my next job is to wrap them with ArrayFormula().

Comment: Bugger!  Been so busy with crypto markets, I haven't even tried ArrayFormula yet.  Have found a few times in the past where AF won't work...  May just stay with "drag down" for the time being.  Cheers.

Comment: @Erik Tyler, if you have an alternative to the formula I'm using - see my comment to player0's Answer - it would be great if you could post it as an answer? Seems this question is getting quite a few views, so may be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B, A3:A, ">="&NOW()-1)
```

---

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B, A3:A, ">="&NOW()-7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Although your formula is not quite correct, it showed me which way to go.  In this example, for C3 I used =SUMIFS(B$3:B$31, A$3:A$31, ">" & (A3-$C$2/24) , A$3:A$31, "<=" & A3  ) and for D3 I used =SUMIFS(B$3:B$31, A$3:A$31, ">" & (A25-$D$2) , A$3:A$31, "<=" & A25  ).

Answer (score 0):

In Google sheets, use the `=TODAY()` code to for today's date and put this in another cell. You could always create a new sheet (which we will call sheet3) which you hide afterwards. Let's imagine you put this in cell A1.

You can use the `=IMPORTRANGE("the google sheets website link", "Sheet Name!A3:A31"` to insert the values. Let's imagine you import this into B3:B31. In C3, you put `=IF(REGEXMATCH(B3, A1), 1, 0)`.

You continue this in each cell from B4:B31, each time changing "B3" to the current row number. Then we can use the `=SUM(C3:C31)` code to count how many meet this condition. Let's imagine you put this in A2.

Now back to the original sheet. Use `=IMPORTRANGE("the google sheets website link", "sheet3!A2" in the cell C3.

For the other 2, I don't know, sorry!

Comment: I have a feeling that INDEX and MATCH needs to be used to create the Range that has to be Summed, but that's out of my league.

Comment: I don't really know because this is my first time trying an issue like such, but I am trying to incorporate other things I have done previously...